# Ubuntu 19: No sound at the Headphone Jack - Audio

Tags: ubuntu, audio, sound-card, alsa

I've a problem with the sound at the Headphone jack on my [Optiplex 9020m](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/optiplex-9020m-desktop/research) after installing Ubuntu 19.04 on it. [Here is what alsa says](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=13a5cc7cf7bf26689f340fb957f469cad475e9ef).

My soundcard is not in the list, and

> lspci | grep -i audio

shows a card as:

> 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core
>   Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)

[In the pavucontrol tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8BrZ.png), that's the only option I have. I don't want to play sound over HDMI, i want to play it over the (not displayed) sound card installed in my PC.

I have checked my sound card, it's an onboard sound card. So i cant' replug it.

Comment: It says you have Pulseaudio, so this is the first thing to check. Do you use GUI? If so, run `pavucontrol` and investigate. Especially Output Devices and Configuration tabs. Screenshots of these tabs showing available entries in drop-down menus may be helpful. By looking at these menus you may be able to figure it out by yourself. I believe Pulse Audio can also be configured via command line, so don't be surprised if somebody tries to guide you this way.

Comment: i posted the answer with the picture, thanks for your help

Comment: _Uros Dobricic_, your 'answer' below was not an answer, so I have moved its content into the original question. The "Audio device:" Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06) won't send audio data to your installed sound card, it will only send to HDMI or DisplayPort.  Please shut down the PC, open it up, and find the sound card; please unplug and replug it, then boot up again. Now, is there a new choice in the pavucontrol 'Port' tab?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and help. I'll try that and then i'll imform you asap.

Comment: Ok, i now checked the sound card of my PC. Its an Onboard card. I cannot unplug and replug it. What you suggest as the next step?

Comment: Ok guys, i found my problem after detail searching.
Thats something i've never heard befor and i have nowhere seen. 
Maybe it will help others too. 
I had to enable the sound card i bios. The "Audio" option i found under general settings, and then "audio".
There i had to enable and then apply, and then i could enable the microphone and the headphone jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem after searching in details.

It's something I've never heard of before and I have not seen. Maybe it will help others too.

I had to enable the sound card in the BIOS. The "Audio" option I found under General settings, and then "audio".

There I had to enable and then apply, and then I could enable the microphone and the headphone jack.

Comment: Didn't work for me on 19.04, this solution worked though: https://superuser.com/a/1329331/46725